# where can I find the pushed code in Heroku

Tags: heroku

I have pushed a project to `Heroku` but I cant figure out how can I see the pushed code there on `Heroku`? Is that possible?

I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you have to connect your app to github to achieve this.